# (Unity) Failed authenticating with google play services on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm having trouble trying to authenticate on my android game, I use playfab + google play services to authenticate on google, but I cant even reach the part where I authenticate on playfab with the google account, the `Social.localUser.Authenticate` never succeeds and the message it returns in the callback is "Authentication canceled", the only useful log messages I get is

> [Play Games Plugin DLL] Application is pausing, which disconnects the
>   RTMP client. Leaving room. Authentication canceled [Play Games Plugin
>   DLL] DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread

sometimes it throws

> [Play Games Plugin DLL] Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status:
>   ERROR_TIMEOUT

or

> [Play Games Plugin DLL] Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status:
>   ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED

but thats about it. The weirdest thing is that it opens up the Google Play Games popup, it asks for the permissions, I accept it and everything goes as it supposed to be but in the application it never succeeds. I already registered the platform addon on the Playfab, added a web app linked on the google developer console, copied the client oauth id and secret to playfab, configured the redirected uri and the endpoint link (refs.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIse9VOk-FE, https://api.playfab.com/docs/tutorials/landing-players/sign-in-with-google). But none of this works, I cant authenticate with it, wether it is installed through the playstore or not, the only thing that I have not tried yet it testing it as an alpha release on the playstore, it is on internal tests at the moment.

[Update 1:]
Code I'm using on awake:

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new 
PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        .AddOauthScope("profile")
        .WithInvitationDelegate(GoogleInvitation)
        .WithMatchDelegate(GoogleMatch)
        .RequestEmail()
        .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
        .RequestIdToken()
        .Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
```

Code I'm using to login:

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate((success, message) =>
    {
        Debug.Log("Authentication Message: " + message);

        if (success)
        {
            var serverAuthCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();
            _AuthService.AuthTicket = serverAuthCode;
            _AuthService.Authenticate(Authtypes.Google);
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("Failed  authenticating with google");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasnt on the testing access list of the app's game services since I wasnt the owner I didnt found out about it. This is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide some code ? First of all i think you need to call

`PlayGamesPlatform.Activate()`

After that all social features should work.

Also to actually test google play services you need to deploy your app to alfa/beta test or release in Play Market and download it from market, without this it won't actually work.

Comment: I'm already calling this function and the app is on alpha as it is downloaded and tested through the market, it still doesnt work (I added the code im using on the question)

Comment: Did you setup google platform with app id, achievments id's and so on ? It can be done through Unity Edtior, just check Google guide.

Comment: yes all of this was done... well, it turns out that I wasnt on another list for testing inside the google play config, im not the owner of the account, now everything else is solved, thank you for your time sir!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "Authentical Cancelled" and solved it [via this post:](https://forum.unity.com/threads/google-play-services-not-working.485322/#post-3210077)

basically, it occured because I allowed google to sign the application with its own key. It was apparent after I went to GooglePlayConsole-> Release Management --> App Signing.

"App Signing by Google Play is enabled for this app".

Because it was enabled, I had to bother about another web page "Google APIs". In there, I had to choose "My Game" from the dropdown in the ribbon, went into Credentials Tab and created a new credential with the appropriate SHA-1.

But the link (in this answer) explains it in more detail.